# What's the reason for the extra renders in this simple React component?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

If I have this code:

```
export const App = () => {
  return <Child />;
};

const Child = () => {
  console.log("RENDER");

  useEffect(() => {
    console.log("EFFECT");
  }, []);

  console.log("RETURN");

  return <div>Hello world</div>;
};
```

The output in the console is:

```
RENDER
RETURN
RENDER
RETURN
EFFECT
EFFECT
```

- Why does the component render fully twice before the useEffect is triggered?
- Why does the effect run twice?

I expected the output to be:

```
RENDER
RETURN
EFFECT
```

(i.e. the component renders and then the useEffect is triggered)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think your main.tsx(or main.jsx) have <React.StrictMode><React.StrictMode>
[Strict Mode](https://react.dev/reference/react/StrictMode)

Comment: You're right! Could you explain why this causes the extra re-renders?

Comment: I linked docs (https://react.dev/reference/react/StrictMode). It is for bugs, mounting twice before rendering, It will check lifecycle, side Effect, legacy code etc...